# Getting the root element that a delegated event is bound to - jQuery

Tags: jquery

Taking the following code:

```
    // Bind the click event to the thumbnails.
    $("ul.hpList").on("click", "a.hpThumb", function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this),

        // Surely there has to be a smarter way to do this.
            $hpList = $this.parents("ul.hpList");

        changeItem($this, $hpList);

    });
```

How do I better identify the root ancestor element that the event is bound to. I feel awful searching the DOM for this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since jQuery 1.7, the [`delegateTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) property is included in the event object given to you as the first parameter, which ([according to the docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/)), gives you:

> The element where the currently-called jQuery event handler was **attached**.

So give the following a go;

```
$("ul.hpList").on("click", "a.hpThumb", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this),
    var $hpList = $(event.delegateTarget);

    changeItem($this, $hpList);
});
```

Comment: @Matt Cheers man. I had a bit of a look through the console after reading your original answer and lo and behold it was there.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `delegateTarget` requires jQuery 1.7 or later.

Comment: @mblase75: I'll update my answer, but of course, if you're using `on`, your using 1.7 :).

Comment: @Matt So you are. :) But we don't know for sure if the OP is, is what I meant.

Comment: Is there an event.delegateTarget alternative for older jQuery versions maybe (e.g. 1.5.x)?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you're actually trying to find, but:

Use [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) inside your handler to determine which actual DOM element triggered the event.

Use `$(this)` to determine which DOM element the handler is attached to, which may be the same thing or may be a parent of the event target.

Use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find an element's closest ancestor which fits a given selector.

Comment: this will give you the opposite of what the question wants. It will give you either `a.hpThumb` or a descendant of `a.hpThumb`. `target` is the element that actually raised the event, not where its being handled in the bubbling life-cycle.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$("ul.hpList").on("click", "a.hpThumb", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
    // Surely there has to be a smarter way to do this.
    $hpList = $("ul.hpList").has($this);
    changeItem($this, $hpList);
 });
```

Comment: @James South please explain, why -1 for me. because result from Matt's and my code is same. please `console.log($hpList);`

Comment: @Matt would you please explain what is wrong with my code line;

Comment: I don't think it's what the OP wants; it's just a *different* way to traverse the DOM. It was my impression that the OP wanted something which didn't require the DOM to be traversed to find the element.

Comment: @theCodeParadox: I didn't mark you down. However as Matt said, I didn't want to traverse the DOM as that is very expensive. Matt was able to give me an in-memory representation of the object I desire thus saving the journey.