# Get container with on() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, event-delegation

I have a button inside a div to hide that div and I want to pass the div to the handler. Here is my current code:

```
$('#hidden-div').on('click', '#hide-btn', { element : $('#hidden-div') }, hideElement);
```

Is there any way to avoid reselecting the container? Something like this would be nice:

```
$('#hidden-div').on('click', '#hide-btn', { element : $(this) }, hideElement);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the element that a delegated event is bound to - jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244350/getting-the-element-that-a-delegated-event-is-bound-to-jquery)

Comment: @FelixKling: this is the second time you busted me and justly because the question you posted is exactly what I wanted :) Due to my limited jQuery vocabulary at the moment, I just couldn't form the correct search query. Please help me close this question.

Comment: Oh is it? :) Don't worry, it's only logical that the more questions exist, more and more will be duplicates. And yes, one of the biggest problems is that you cannot find a solution/question, when you don't know what you have to look for ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`event.delegateTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) holds a DOM element reference.

```
$('#hidden-div').on('click', '#hide-btn', hideElement);

function hideElement(e) {
    $(e.delegateTarget)//do stuff
}
```

You'd still have to wrap it inside a jQuery object, but creating jQuery objects from DOM element references does not query the DOM.