# How to get the current element when event on child?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event listener on child element but I want to get the current element.

Example code:

```js
$(".video").on("click", "img", function(e) {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(e.currentTarget);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video">
  <img src="video_1.png" />
  <span>Video 1</span>
</div>

<div class="video">
 <img src="video_2.png" />
 <span>Video 2</span>
</div>
```

In this example, I want to get the `.video` element, not `img`. What's the best way to do it?

I know `$(this).parent()` and `$(this).closest(".video")`, but I am looking for a better way. The real situation is not just a parent and `closest` search will cost time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the root element that a delegated event is bound to - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244350/getting-the-root-element-that-a-delegated-event-is-bound-to-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can use the [`delegateTarget` property](https://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) of the event:

```js
$(".video").on("click", "img", function(e) {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(e.delegateTarget);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video">
  <img src="video_1.png" />
  <span>Video 1</span>
</div>

<div class="video">
  <img src="video_2.png" />
  <span>Video 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! That's the answer I want.

Answer (score 0):

Use parents ([selector]);

```
$(this).parents(".video")
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers, one can also use the "closest" method

```
$(".video").on("click", "img", function(e) {    
  console.log( $(this).closest('.video') )
})
```